# How to emulate the phantomjs behavior with chromedriver and chrome to get all links on a page using Selenium through Python and contextlib

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs, google-chrome-headless, contextmanager

Some webpages I encounter have links that are generated from a javascript code and I can only access them with phantomjs as per the code below.

```
 dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
        dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"
        driverpjs = webdriver.PhantomJS("/Users/xx/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs",desired_capabilities=dcap)

with contextlib.closing(driverpjs) as browser:
                browser.get(link)
                links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
```

How do I do this with chrome ? Right now I am trying the below:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("headless")
    options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"')
        driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)

with contextlib.closing(driver) as browser:
                browser.get(link)

                # GET ALL LINKS                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                #links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")                                                                                                                                                                       
                links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all links on a page emulating the similar functionality of *PhantomJS* with *Chrome* using **`contextlib`** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from contextlib import closing
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("headless")
  options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"')
  driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

  with closing(driver) as browser:
      browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
      # get all the elements with name as q                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      print(browser.find_elements_by_name('q'))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ab581b3b679b521ffa5bf2220f801fcf", element="0.39081088826075705-1")>]
  ```

Comment: @user11020868 Can I get a feedback on this answer please?